# Help on using structural induction for set equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, induction

Denote $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ the set of polynomials on one variable $x$ with integer coefficients.
For example, $p(x)=x^2-3x+42$ is such a polynomial, whereas $q(x)=-1.5x^3+97x$ is not

Let's define the set $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ using the following rules:

$$2\in S$$
$$x\in S$$
$$\forall p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x], \forall q(x)\in S,\,\, p(x)q(x)\in S$$
$$\forall p(x),q(x) \in S,\,\, p(x)+q(x)\in S$$

Also define the set $T=\{2p(x)+xq(x)|p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}$.
Prove $S=T$.
$$$$
I know the prove will be $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$

For $S \subseteq T$ I want to use structural induction to show every element of $S$ satisfies the property of $T$ but I don't understand what the properties of T are so I can define a predicate that I can use.

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand the definition of the set $T$?

Comment: Yes I don't understand what are the conditions of T

Comment: The condition on T is every one of them has the form 2p(x)+xq(x).

Comment: Wasn't this question just posted the other day?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924529/structural-induction-with-sets-question deleted by the poster after someone else claimed it was an assigned homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that the rules defining S hold for T.
Then since by definition, S is the smallest
set for which the rules hold, S subset T.

Comment: Would the predicate be $P(x) : 2p(x) + xq(x)$? When proving the base case $2\in S$ how do we show $P(2) holds?

Comment: To show 2 in T, set p = 1, q = 0.